# Unable to resolve the DNS address in Azure

Tags: azure, firewall, azure-dns

I have a Hub-Spoke model. I also have an Azure DNS zone. I have a firewall in the Hub and Spoke uses Route table(s). I have created a VM in the Spoke and added the 'A' record in the Azure DNS zone, however, I am unable to resolve the DNS address in Azure.

I have an Azure Firewall with the following Roles

```
# Create a Azure Firewall Network Rule for DNS
resource "azurerm_firewall_network_rule_collection" "fw-net-dns" {
  name                = "azure-firewall-dns-rule"
  azure_firewall_name = azurerm_firewall.azufw.name
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.ipz12-dat-np-connection-rg.name
  priority            = 102
  action              = "Allow"

  rule {
    name = "DNS"
    source_addresses = [
      "*",
    ]
    destination_ports = ["53"]
    destination_addresses = [
      "*",
    ]
    protocols = ["TCP","UDP"]
  }
}
```

I have a Route Table with the below Routes

```
resource "azurerm_route_table" "azurt" {
  name                          = "AzfwRouteTable"
  resource_group_name           = azurerm_resource_group.ipz12-dat-np-connection-rg.name
  location                      = azurerm_resource_group.ipz12-dat-np-connection-rg.location
  disable_bgp_route_propagation = false

  route {
    name                   = "AzgwRoute"
    address_prefix         = "10.2.3.0/24" // CIDR of 2nd SPOKE
    next_hop_type          = "VirtualNetworkGateway"
  }  

  route {
    name                   = "Internet"
    address_prefix         = "0.0.0.0/0"
    next_hop_type          = "VirtualAppliance"
    next_hop_in_ip_address = azurerm_firewall.azufw.ip_configuration.0.private_ip_address
  }  

  tags = {
    environment = "Staging"
    owner       = "Someone@contoso.com"
    costcenter  = "IT"
  }

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_resource_group.ipz12-dat-np-connection-rg
  ]
}
```

It is associated with the subnet

```
resource "azurerm_subnet_route_table_association" "virtual_machine_subnet_route_table_assc" {
  subnet_id      = azurerm_subnet.virtual_machine_subnet.id
  route_table_id = azurerm_route_table.azurt.id

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_route_table.azurt,
    azurerm_subnet.virtual_machine_subnet
  ]
}
```

I have a VM in the above mentioned subnet

```
resource "azurerm_network_interface" "virtual_machine_nic" {
  name                = "virtal-machine-nic"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.ipz12-dat-np-applications-rg.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.ipz12-dat-np-applications-rg.name

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = data.azurerm_subnet.virtual_machine_subnet.id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
  }

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_resource_group.ipz12-dat-np-applications-rg
  ]  
}

resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "virtual_machine" {
  name                = "virtual-machine"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.ipz12-dat-np-applications-rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.ipz12-dat-np-applications-rg.location
  size                = "Standard_B1ms"
  admin_username      = "...."
  admin_password      = "...."
  network_interface_ids = [
    azurerm_network_interface.virtual_machine_nic.id
  ]

  os_disk {
    caching              = "ReadWrite"
    storage_account_type = "Standard_LRS"
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = "MicrosoftWindowsDesktop"
    offer     = "Windows-10"
    sku       = "21h1-pro"
    version   = "latest"
  }

  depends_on = [
    azurerm_network_interface.virtual_machine_nic
  ]    
}
```

I have created a Azure DNS Zone

```
resource "azurerm_dns_zone" "dns_zone" {
  name                = "learnpluralsight.com"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.ipz12-dat-np-connection-rg.name
  
  depends_on = [
    azurerm_resource_group.ipz12-dat-np-connection-rg
  ]  
}
```

and added the 'A' record

[image]

But I am not able to resolve the FQDN

[image]

Comment: Do you own `learnpluralsight.com` domain?

Answer (score 2):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment I am getting same request timed out**.

[image]

To resolve this issue, you need to ***add Reverse lookup zone*** and Create ***PTR record for DNS server*** name and IP.

[image]

***In Reverse lookup zone -> right click choose new zone***

[image]

[image]

***Click Next as a primary zone -> check the store the zone box ->Next -> click the 2nd option all the dns server...in the domain -> IPv4 reverse lookup -> Next***

Here you should add your Ip address as **150.171.10** 1st three octets -> ***click next -> choose to allow only secure dynamic -> next -> Finish***

[image]

Once you ***refresh*** your default records are added and right click and create pointer (PTR) like below type your ip address **150.171.10.35** and provide your ***host name*** and your PTR will be added successfully

[image]

And when I run nslookup server run successfully without request timed out.

[image]

---

If this still ***persist*** in your search box -> network and internet -> ethernet -> Right click ->properties -> internet protocol version provide DNS server as below.

*Still any issue occurs try:*

*preferred dns server as 8.8.8.8
Alternate DNS server as 8.8.4.4
or

preferred dns server as 8.8.8.8
Alternate DNS server as Your ip*

***Reference***: [dns request timeout (spiceworks.com)](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/2106622-dns-request-timeout)

[image]

Check whether you have given IPv6 as obtain DNS server automatically or else uncheck it.

[image]